# How did 'sitting' semantically shift to mean 'properness'?

Tags: etymology

What semantic notions underlie 'sit' and 'properness'? The following words for propriety hail from the  [Proto-Indo-European](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language) *[*sed-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/sed-)* like

- Spanish & Portugese [sentar](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sentar)
- French [seoir](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/seoir#French)
- English 'sit well'

I don't know if Italian [sedere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sedere#Italian) or Romanian`s equivalent shifted semantically.

Comment: That's actually an easy one. Rulers sit, subjects stand. Those who are allowed to sit are noble, and their behavior defines propriety. A judge who is in office is said to be a sitting judge. A monarch is said to be on the throne. The pope issues encyclicals _ex cathedra_ 'from the chair'.

Comment: @jlawler If only I can be as shrewd as you!

Comment: @jlawler, you don't think that's an answer?

Comment: Can you add the 'proper' meanings to the text of the question (in case the links rot). Also, wikipedia is questionable, can you give other sources (and quotes) for these 'proper' meanings?

Comment: German *Sitte* "etiquette, tradition, ethos", adv. *sittsam*; I suppose a connection to *sesshaft*, "settled" (cp. *gesessen*, perfekt "sat") and thus *civilized*. Also I like to compare PIE \*ses "sleep".

Comment: @jlawler Ger *Niederlassung* "branch office", *sich niederlassen* "to settle down", *Erlass* "edict" come to mind due to *cath-*, cp. Gr *kata* "down" (I love playing on that word).

Comment: Regarding \*ses, it is supposed to be from an older strata; Compare *sedate* and for analogy see *pax* "peace", PIE "to join, attach; agreement, settlement", and *pacify* somewhat euphemistically "to conquer or otherwise reign a region, overcomming the *resistance*", whence also *to fasten*, Ger *fest* "solid" (thus cp. *truce*), *Festung* "fortification" (analoguously *Fried, Einfriedung* "fenced, fortified", versus *Frieden* "peace"). Not sure how much Latin or rather catholic influence this shows. A *Sitzung* "meeting" is pretty transparent. *feste Abmachung* is idiomatic. cf. *free will*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That's actually an easy one. Rulers sit, subjects stand. Those who are allowed to sit are noble, and their behavior defines propriety. A judge who is in office is said to be a sitting judge. A monarch is said to be on the throne. The pope issues encyclicals *ex cathedra* 'from the chair'. – [jlawler](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/482/jlawler) [Jul 23 at 20:45](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/31974/how-did-sitting-semantically-shift-to-mean-properness#comment70008_31974)